# RewriteURL Question - PHP

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this setup right now...

```
RewriteRule ^/?user userpanel.php
RewriteRule ^/?user/?newListing newListing.php
```

The above works for only /user goes to userpanel.php like it should but when I try to access /user/newListing it still takes me to userpanel.php, is there something I am missing with that?

Thank you so much ahead of time!

Comment: This is Apache [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), not PHP, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch the order of these and you should be ok.

Comment: Thanks for your help as well, I completely understand now!

Answer (score 0):

The expressions are run in order, and because `/user/newListing` is still valid by `^/?user` it goes to the ucp.  try making the first rule a little more strict, something like `^/?user/?$` now nothing can follow it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I made it more strict and works perfectly, I REALLY need to brush on my mod_rewrite skills! =D

Comment: Another suggestion, you might want to take off the first `?` after the `/`, it basically says that it could be example.com/usernewListing (makes no sense), instead I would put that at the end, so there can be a following slash (or not).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a dollar sign at the end of the first rule? That would make sure the url must end with user

```
RewriteRule ^/?user$ userpanel.php
```